# Вопрос про View view, Menu menu, view v

Tags: android, view, android-menu

Я только начинаю изучать Андройд и Java.
Начал встречать подобные конструкции, но пока не могу понять, почему мы пишем 2 раза View view или Menu menu или View v.

```
...
public void doSomething (View view){
        //получаем ссылку на TextView
        TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
...

...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
...
```

Буду благодарен, если объясните простыми словами

Comment: Это класс и имя переменной. Как `String s` или `String string`

Answer (score 1):

В языке программирования Java, который используется для написания программ для платформы Android, строгая типизация переменных. Это значит, что для каждой переменной мы обязаны указать ее тип явно.

В вашем примере мы объявляем переменную с именем *view* типа `View`. Имя переменной мы можем выбрать любое, по своему усмотрению, написать, например `View name1`, а вот тип переменной (тот класс, который переменная представляет) мы выбрать уже не можем и обязаны указать именно тот, объект какого класса будет создан.

Указывать тип переменной необходимо только при ее инициализации, при обращении к переменной этого делать нельзя (иначе это будет опять инициализация новой переменной).

Так же в Java принято соглашение, что имена классов пишутся с большой буквы, а переменных с маленькой, то есть вашем случае объявляется переменная с именем view типа (класса) View. Хотя компилятор разберется, что здесь к чему и без заглавных и прописных букв, так как синтаксис языка имеет четкий порядок, человеку проще читать код, поддерживающий такие соглашения.

PS: вообще это все можно узнать буквально на первых страницах любого учебника по Java. Рекомендую почитать один из них, там вас ждет еще много удивительных вещей и открытий.